# ASP.NET Web API response result Format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET Web API.

My model is

```
public class DataModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

     [XmlText]
    public string RowList { get; set; }
}
```

The RowList property is xml .

the response as show follow:

[The image of the response xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6Zim.png)

Now the result in xml format, but The response result was encoded.
How could I decode the RowList in a right format before I response the result to client.

Thanks.

Comment: As long as its valid xml it will work fine when parsed. That looks like fiddler, have you checked the xml tab? If you want a example of decoding the xml let me know.

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem. Set the RowList as XmlElement type,then everything work fine.